# How to slice MultiIndex and column?

Tags: python, pandas

```
midx = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['zero', 'one'], ['x', 'y']],labels = [[1, 1, 0, 0],[1, 0, 1, 0]])
        df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 2), index=midx)

>>midx
               0         1
one  y  0.477304  0.247328
     x -1.267339 -1.779735
zero y  0.812613  1.119952
     x  0.092788  0.384020
```

## A more readable way of doing this? have tried df.loc['one',1] no luck..

```
df.xs('one')[1]
Out[44]: 
y    0.247328
x   -1.779735
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
In [74]: df.loc['one', 1]
Out[74]:
y    0.247328
x   -1.779735
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

or more explicitly:

```
In [80]: df.loc[pd.IndexSlice['one', :], 1]
Out[80]:
one  y    0.247328
     x   -1.779735
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Could you please fix the formatting issues in the question. I can't do it because I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Doesn't the question say `df.loc['one',1]` has already been tried? Maybe edit the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `pd.IndexSlice`, you can use `pd.DataFrame.query` and select your column in a separate step:

```
res = df.query('ilevel_0 == "one"').loc[:, 1]
```

As per [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html?highlight=sort#the-query-method), `ilevel_0` is used to represent the first unnamed index. For clarity, you can replace this with a genuine name if you defined it as such when you construct the dataframe.